# Как сделать мигание на панели задач?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, tkinter

Есть программа на подобие чата. Пользователей около 5. Обмен информацией не постоянный, то есть пишут по необходимости и могут быть большие временные перерывы. Хочу сделать так, чтобы после того как кто-то написал сообщение можно было привлечь внимание других пользователей у которых запущена программа. Звук без вариантов (колонок нет). В идеале было бы мигание программы на панели. Программа будет работать на windows server 2008 r2.
В гугле не могу найти ничего применимого к Python (у меня 3.4).
Это моя первая программа.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import time

name = str()
fname = str(time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y"))

def messange():
    global mdname
    if entry.get() < '0':
        mb.showerror('Ошибка', 'Вы не написали сообщение, сообщение не должно начинаться с пробела') # Ошибка
    else:
        mess = entry.get()
        entry.delete(0, END)
        f = open(fname + '.txt', 'a')
        f.write(time.strftime("%H:%M") + ' ' + name + ' пишет: ' + mess + '\n')
        f.close()

def login(event):
    global name
    name = entry.get()
    if name < '0':
        mb.showerror('Ошибка', 'Напишите ваше имя, имя не должно начинаться с пробела') # Ошибка
    else:
        event.widget.pack_forget() # Скрыть скнопку
        name = entry.get()
        entry.delete(0, END)
        f = open(fname + '.txt', 'a')
        f.write('Привет ' + name + '\n')
        f.close()
        button_visible_false.pack() # Отобразить кнопку
        while True:
            f = open(fname + '.txt')
            data = f.read()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            f.close()
            textbox.delete(1.0, END)
            textbox.insert(1.0, data)
            textbox.see("end")
            root.update_idletasks()
            root.update()

root = Tk()
root.title('Гармоничный чат v.1')

panelFrame = Frame(root, height = 60, bg = 'green')
textFrame = Frame(root, height = 340, width = 600)
panelFrame.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')
textFrame.pack(side = 'bottom', fill = 'both', expand = 1)

textbox = Text(textFrame, font='Arial 10', wrap='word')
scrollbar = Scrollbar(textFrame)

scrollbar['command'] = textbox.yview
textbox['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

textbox.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'both', expand = 1)
scrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')

entry = Entry(width = 80)
entry.pack(pady = 10)

btn1 = Button(panelFrame, text='Напишите ваше имя', width=17, height=3, bg="white", fg="black")
btn1.bind('<Button-1>', login)
btn1.pack()
button_visible_false = tkinter.Button(panelFrame, text='Написать сообщение', width=17, height=3, bg="white", fg="black", command = messange)

try:
    f = open(fname + '.txt')
except:
    f = open(fname + '.txt', 'w')
else:
    pass

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10):

Для мигания можно использовать функцию [`FlashWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow):

```
import ctypes
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def flash_window():
    hwnd = int(root.wm_frame(), 16)  # wm_frame() возвращает хэндл окна в виде строки в 16-ричной системе, переводим в число
    ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindow(hwnd, True)


root.after(1000, flash_window)
root.mainloop()
```

Активное окно мигнет один раз, свернутое подсветится (по крайней мере на Windows7 работает так).

Не обязательно нужно делать через `after`, достаточно чтобы функция `flash_window` вызывалась откуда-то из обработчика событий, уже после запуска `root.mainloop()`.

Чтобы мигнуть несколько раз, можно использовать [`FlashWindowEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex) (это немного сложнее из-за того, что данные в функцию передаются через структуру [`FLASHINFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-flashwinfo)):

```
import ctypes
import tkinter as tk


class FLASHWINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cbSize", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("hwnd", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("uCount", ctypes.c_uint),
        ("dwTimeout", ctypes.c_uint)
    ]

    # Codes for dwFlags
    FLASHW_ALL = 3  # Flash both the window caption and taskbar button. This is equivalent to setting the FLASHW_CAPTION | FLASHW_TRAY flags.
    FLASHW_CAPTION = 1  # Flash the window caption.
    FLASHW_STOP = 0  # Stop flashing. The system restores the window to its original state.
    FLASHW_TIMER = 4  # Flash continuously, until the FLASHW_STOP flag is set.
    FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 0xC  # Flash continuously until the window comes to the foreground.
    FLASHW_TRAY = 2  # Flash the taskbar button.

    def __init__(self, hwnd, dwFlags, uCount, dwTimeout):
        super().__init__()
        self.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(self)
        self.hwnd = hwnd
        self.dwFlags = dwFlags
        self.uCount = uCount
        self.dwTimeout = dwTimeout


root = tk.Tk()


def flash_window():
    hwnd = int(root.wm_frame(), 16)
    flashinfo = FLASHWINFO(hwnd, FLASHWINFO.FLASHW_ALL, 3, 100)
    ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindowEx(ctypes.byref(flashinfo))


root.after(1000, flash_window)
root.mainloop()
```